# Get variable of radio button with right click

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button, right-click

I am trying to get the value of a radiobutton in tkinter when it is right-clicked but i just returns the last value that was left-clicked. Here is my code please help.

```
from tkinter import *

master=Tk()
master.geometry("600x650")


def rightclick(event):
    print (number.get())

def leftclick(event):
    global left,right
    print (number.get())

row = -1
number=IntVar()

for w in range (10**2):
    column =w
    if w % 10==0:
        row +=1
    column-=row*10


    button=Radiobutton(master,padx=25,pady=18.35,variable=number ,bg= "green",indicatoron=0, value=w)
    button.bind("<Button-3>",rightclick)
    button.bind("<Button-1>", leftclick)

    button.grid(row=row,column=column)
```

Comment: This may require `mainloop()` in order to be able to run standalone.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
def rightclick(event):
    print (number.get())

...

    button.bind("<Button-3>",rightclick)
```

with:

```
def rightclick(widget):
    print(widget['value'])

...

    button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e, w=button: rightclick(w))
```

Which makes it so that an anonymous reference(`lambda`) is called when the rightmost button on the mouse is clicked with. That anonymous reference takes two arguments, `e` as the event argument, and `w` as the widget object argument. It then calls a sub function `rightclick` with the widget argument. `rightclick` then prints the `value` of the `widget` it is passed to screen.